# Fitting piecewise functions

Tags: fitting, piecewise

I have several large data sets which follow the following pattern: A position is measured, a force is applied until a new equilibrium is found.
I'd like to find a fit for the position, at least at the plateaus, and preferably of the inter lying section, which in this case approaches a line.
I tried fitting the data with `Clip`, and with `Piecewise`.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[v40s1000h,Piecewise[{{a, x < A}, {b, x > B}}], {a, b, A, B, c, d}, x]
```

This creates a decent fit only if I specify the values for A and B, but then I have to estimate those values for each data set manually. It also doesn't really work to just add `NMinimize`, or add the piecewise part for the middle bit.
Is There anything else I can try?

[image: Setting the A to 200 and B to 250 works decently.]

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=35616536027018518052 << file

Comment: Could you post a link to the dataset `v40s1000h`. An idea would be to create the first few terms of a Fourier expansion and fit that within the domain of interest.

Comment: @Feyre I don't understand, you're saying that you need to manually specify A,B, but in your example you are fitting the parameters A,B.

Comment: How about fitting a sigmoid?

Comment: I think `NonlinearModelFit` works my minimizing some cost function (e.g. total squared error), but the cost function can't be evaluated if your piecewise function doesn't return a value for some values of x. Have you tried using something like `{(a+b)/2,A<x<B}` as a fallback? Alternatively, you could come up with your own cost function and just optimize that.

Comment: well, these are guesses I made, and they fit, the images was made with those guesses, which does work, but I'd have to guess for each separate file. Fitting with just the parameters A and B yields just a single straight line, and it tries to fit them around ~13x.  

gpap, Peltio I haven't had too much maths yet, I know basic Fourier series and transforms, but that's it. Could you give more of an idea (or a link) on how to try this in Mathematica?

Comment: File:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=35616536027018518052

Comment: @nikie  
The original was: `Piecewise[{{a, x < A}, {c x + d, A < x < B}, {b, x > B}}]`, which yields a single straight line.

Comment: @Feyre, could you put that file up somewhere else? Some proxies (like the one I'm behind) evidently block tinyupload.com as a high risk site? It's only about a dozen kiB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[As usual](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42132/484), it's a matter of choosing a better starting values for the parameters.

I started writing this answer before the data file was uploaded, so here's some synthetic data:

```
data = Table[
   Interpolation[{{0, 1.1*^-6}, {200, 1.1*^-6}, {250, 9.5*^-7}, {500, 
       9.5*^-7}}, x, InterpolationOrder -> 1] + 
    2*^-8 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {x, 0, 500}];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

As @nikie suggested in the comments, you should define your model to return something in the intermediate values. I'll use a linear transition because that seems to match your data.

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{a, x < xa}, {a + (b - a) (x - xa)/(xb - xa), xa <= x < xb}, {b, xb <= x}}]
```

Now we do the fit:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[x], {a, b, xa, xb}, x];
fit // Normal // InputForm
(* Piecewise[{{1., x < 1.}, {1.016964195743597*^-6, 1. <= x}}, 0] *)
```

No good. Why? The documentation for `NonlinearModelFit` says "give starting values when parameters are far from the default value 1". Let's try that.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, f[x], {a, b, {xa, 100}, {xb, 200}}, x];
fit // Normal // InputForm
(* Piecewise[{{1.1004729741760495*^-6, x < 200.73035367387615}, 
  {1.1004729741760495*^-6 - 2.914483888454594*^-9*(-200.73035367387615 + x), 
   200.73035367387615 <= x < 253.00000699926912}, 
  {9.481339117040847*^-7, 253.00000699926912 <= x}}, 0] *)
```

That's better.

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
```

[image]