# Looking for ideas for handling a complicated fitting problem

Tags: plotting, fitting, data

I have the following data:

```
test={{{15.8257, -0.0769379}, {16.1561, -0.0974535}, {16.4865, 
-0.0896821}, {16.5195, -0.065402}, {16.6847, -0.0581635}, {16.8499, 
-0.0702727}, {17.0151, -0.0836196}, {17.1803, -0.0888208}, {17.3455, 
-0.0929545}, {17.5107, -0.105148}, {17.6759, -0.103528}, {17.8411, 
-0.0836455}, {18.0063, -0.0715808}, {18.1715, -0.0650529}, {18.3366, 
-0.0582498}, {18.5018, -0.0588228}, {18.667, -0.0599082}, {18.8322, 
-0.0605835}, {18.9974, -0.0664554}, {19.1626, -0.0695087}, {19.3278, 
-0.0696179}, {19.493, -0.0734236}, {19.6582, -0.0709082}, {19.8234, 
-0.0622981}, {19.9886, -0.0673829}, {20.1538, -0.0802961}, {20.319, 
-0.0798284}, {20.4842, -0.0687257}, {20.6494, -0.0717655}, {20.8146, 
-0.0806611}, {20.9798, -0.085287}, {21.145, -0.0922109}, {21.3102, 
-0.0944269}, {21.4754, -0.0878644}, {21.6405, -0.0880898}, {21.8057, 
-0.0899869}, {21.9709, -0.078788}, {22.1361, -0.0591576}, {22.3013, 
-0.044466}, {22.4665, -0.0600192}, {22.6317, -0.0748474}, {22.7969, 
-0.0704493}, {22.9621, -0.0572922}, {23.1273, -0.0562575}, {23.2925, 
-0.0623347}, {23.4577, -0.0634224}, {23.6229, -0.068166}, {23.7881, 
-0.0829702}, {23.9533, -0.0888241}, {24.1185, -0.0735696}, {24.2837, 
-0.0593534}, {24.4489, -0.0637424}, {24.6141, -0.0650974}, {24.7793, 
-0.0519863}, {24.9444, -0.0404489}, {25.1096, -0.0633278}, {25.2748, 
-0.0747063}, {25.44, -0.0698835}, {25.6052, -0.0770221}, {25.7704, 
-0.0828237}, {25.9356, -0.0727494}, {26.1008, -0.0432394}, {26.266, 
-0.0423326}, {26.4312, -0.06231}, {26.5964, -0.0736631}, {26.7616,
-0.0655702}, {26.9268, -0.0632276}, {27.092, -0.0749202}, {27.2572, 
-0.0780181}, {27.4224, -0.0727166}, {27.5876, -0.0615335}, {27.7528, 
-0.056091}, {27.918, -0.063779}, {28.0832, -0.0615237}, {28.2483, 
-0.0506654}, {28.4135, -0.0563894}, {28.5787, -0.0836379}, {28.7439, 
-0.0994342}, {28.9091, -0.0896401}, {29.0743, -0.0615194}, {29.2395, 
-0.0517822}, {29.4047, -0.062227}, {29.5699, -0.0769844}, {29.7351, 
-0.0813083}, {29.9003, -0.0899082}, {30.0655, -0.0893884}, {30.2307, 
-0.0725808}, {30.3959, -0.050268}, {30.5611, -0.0426449}, {30.7263, 
-0.0480701}, {30.8915, -0.0559944}, {31.0567, -0.0608699}, {31.2219, 
-0.06694}, {31.3871, -0.0797316}, {31.5522, -0.0904721}, {31.7174, 
-0.0867335}, {31.8826, -0.0808754}, {32.0478, -0.0764141}, {32.213, 
-0.0672197}, {32.3782, -0.0500709}, {32.5434, -0.0431931}, {32.7086, 
-0.0477298}, {32.8738, -0.0606955}, {33.039, -0.072429}, {33.2042, 
-0.0820698}, {33.3694, -0.100112}, {33.5346, -0.0911248}, {33.6998, 
-0.0722954}, {33.865, -0.0553945}, {34.0302, -0.0577424}, {34.1954, 
   0.267945}, {34.3606, 0.580552}, {34.5258, 0.665223}, {34.6579, 
   0.755472}, {34.8231, 0.759053}, {34.9883, 0.76307}, {35.1535, 
   0.776505}, {35.3187, 
   0.779363}, {35.4839, -1.12199}, {35.6491, -2.55552}, {35.8143, 
-2.94135}, {35.9795, -3.09798}, {36.1447, -3.19286}, {36.3099, 
-3.20814}, {36.4751, -3.20919}, {36.6403, -3.21143}, {36.8054, 
-3.22794}, {36.9706, -3.23869}, {37.1358, -3.22691}, {37.301, 
-3.22079}, {37.4662, -3.23454}, {37.6314, -3.23401}, {37.7966, 
-3.21475}, {37.9618, -3.20351}, {38.127, -3.19776}, {38.2922, 
-3.20082}, {38.4574, -3.20999}, {38.6226, -3.20835}, {38.7878, 
-3.22132}, {38.953, -3.24514}, {39.1182, -3.23904}, {39.2834, 
-3.22584}, {39.4486, -3.22737}, {39.6138, -3.21398}, {39.779, 
-3.19581}, {39.9442, -3.18892}, {40.1093, -3.18855}, {40.2745, 
-3.20021}, {40.4397, -3.21298}, {40.6049, -3.21224}, {40.7701, 
-3.20945}, {40.9353, -3.21391}, {41.1005, -3.20505}, {41.2657, 
-3.195}, {41.4309, -3.19082}, {41.5961, -3.19234}, {41.7613, 
-3.19255}, {41.9265, -3.18381}, {42.0917, -3.20026}, {42.2569, 
-3.2267}, {42.4221, -3.24796}, {42.5873, -3.24242}, {42.7525, 
-3.23463}, {42.9177, -3.229}, {43.0829, -3.21687}, {43.2481, 
-3.19914}, {43.4132, -3.17638}, {43.5784, -3.17475}, {43.7436, 
-3.1944}, {43.9088, -3.22259}, {44.074, -3.23448}, {44.2392, 
-3.23701}, {44.4044, -3.25577}, {44.5696, -3.25209}, {44.7348, 
-3.2347}, {44.9, -3.20355}, {45.0652, -3.18403}, {45.2304, -3.1984}, 
{45.3956, -3.2077}, {45.5608, -3.20139}, {45.726, -3.18804}, 
{45.8912, -3.19259}, {46.0564, -3.22305}, {46.2216, -3.23381}, 
{46.3868, -3.21896}, {46.552, -3.19782}, {46.7171, -3.19925}, 
{46.8823, -3.21254}, {47.0475, -3.20822}, {47.2127, -3.20076}, 
{47.3779, -3.21503}, {47.5431, -3.23415}, {47.7083, -3.23585}, 
{47.8735, -3.21257}, {48.0387, -3.19277}, {48.2039, -3.21066}, 
{48.3691, -3.23566}, {48.5343, -3.23804}, {48.6995, -3.22519}, 
{48.8647, -3.22}, {49.0299, -3.22857}, {49.1951, -3.22214}, {49.3603, 
-3.18748}, {49.5255, -3.17048}, {49.6907, -3.18617}, {49.8559, 
-3.20105}, {50.021, -3.19556}, {50.1862, -3.19728}, {50.3514, 
-3.22789}, {50.5166, -3.25828}, {50.6818, -3.252}, {50.847, 
-3.22992}, {51.0122, -3.23513}, {51.1774, -3.23703}, {51.3426, 
-3.19712}, {51.5078, -3.1469}, {51.673, -3.15768}, {51.8382, 
-3.19598}, {52.0034, -3.22341}, {52.1686, -3.22205}, {52.3338, 
-3.21716}, {52.499, -3.24412}, {52.6642, -3.25222}, {52.8294, 
-3.22671}, {52.9946, -3.2061}, {53.1598, -3.21205}, {53.3249, 
-3.20663}, {53.4901, -3.1892}, {53.6553, -3.18521}, {53.8205, 
-3.21223}, {53.9857, -3.22453}, {54.1509, -3.21086}, {54.3161, 
-3.20821}, {54.4813, -1.83753}, {54.6465, -0.497467}, {54.8117, 
-0.172629}, {54.9769, -0.118185}, {55.1421, -0.0401817}, {55.3073, 
-0.0390328}, {55.4725, -0.0519028}, {55.6377, -0.0341139}, {55.8029, 
-0.0159919}, {55.9681, -0.0322755}, {56.1333, -0.0560436}, {56.2985, 
-0.055005}, {56.4637, -0.0382538}, {56.6288, -0.0461829}, {56.794, 
-0.0519669}, {56.9592, -0.0478512}, {57.1244, -0.0485063}, {57.2896, 
-0.0450605}, {57.4548, -0.0328684}, {57.62, -0.0012728}, {57.7852, 
   0.000699344}, {57.9504, -0.0282098}, {58.1156, -0.0528248}, 
{58.2808, -0.0660222}, {58.446, -0.0670143}, {58.6112, -0.0803909}, 
{58.7764, -0.0722626}, {58.9416, -0.056143}, {59.1068, -0.052108}, 
{59.272, -0.041373}, {59.4372, -0.0346966}, {59.6024, -0.0253502}, 
{59.7676, -0.0264026}, {59.9327, -0.0481955}, {60.0979, -0.0662766}, 
{60.2631, -0.068389}, {60.4283, -0.0613654}, {60.5935, -0.0516283}, 
{60.7587, -0.0460859}, {60.9239, -0.026215}, {61.0891, -0.0075962}, 
{61.2543, -0.0158598}, {61.4195, -0.0383789}, {61.5847, -0.052961}, 
{61.7499, -0.0406836}, {61.9151, -0.0423972}, {62.0803, -0.0769325}, 
{62.2455, -0.0948179}, {62.4107, -0.0665865}, {62.5759, -0.0433503}, 
{62.7411, -0.0465402}, {62.9063, -0.064464}, {63.0715, -0.0543498}, 
{63.2366, -0.0287138}, {63.4018, -0.0410531}, {63.567, -0.0596464}, 
{63.7322, -0.0323676}, {63.8974, -0.00447797}, {64.0626, -0.0176177}, 
{64.2278, -0.0278519}, {64.393, -0.0175132}, {64.5582, -0.0343388}, 
{64.7234, -0.0728937}, {64.8886, -0.0859438}, {65.0538, -0.0851371}, 
{65.219, -0.0734951}, {65.3842, -0.0496842}, {65.5494, -0.00584685}, 
{65.7146, 
   0.0095625}, {65.8798, -0.00930119}, {66.045, -0.0250789}, 
{66.2102, -0.0359847}, {66.3754, -0.0667467}, {66.5405, -0.09646}, 
{66.7057, -0.0840331}, {66.8709, -0.0524984}, {67.0361, -0.0383522}, 
{67.2013, -0.0540666}, {67.3665, -0.0645649}, {67.5317, -0.0412653}, 
{67.6969, -0.0161336}, {67.8621, -0.037667}, {68.0273, -0.0628333}, 
{68.1925, -0.0356986}, {68.3577, -0.0229571}, {68.5229, -0.0403972}, 
{68.6881, -0.0403037}, {68.8533, -0.0353493}, {69.0185, -0.0300052}, 
{69.1837, -0.0497527}, {69.3489, -0.0725242}, {69.5141, -0.0655332}, 
{69.6793, -0.0600311}, {69.8444, -0.0536261}, {70.0096, -0.051527}, 
{70.1748, -0.045936}, {70.34, -0.0338074}, {70.5052, -0.0315814}, 
{70.6704, -0.0265081}, {70.8356, -0.0228345}, {71.0008, -0.0348291}, 
{71.166, -0.0534865}, {71.3312, -0.0559775}, {71.4964, -0.0523304}, 
{71.6616, -0.0514005}, {71.8268, -0.0403854}, {71.992, -0.0236734}, 
{72.1572, -0.0114473}, {72.3224, -0.0182658}, {72.4876, -0.0314441}, 
{72.6528, -0.0284464}, {72.818, -0.0324639}, {72.9832, -0.0492846}, 
{73.1483, -0.0854126}, {73.3135, -0.0898038}, {73.4787, -0.0559581}, 
{73.6439, -0.0413622}, {73.8091, -0.051359}, {73.9743, -0.058296}, 
{74.1395, -0.0417273}, {74.3047, -0.0255182}, {74.4699, -0.0485516}, 
{74.6351, -0.0663423}, {74.8003, -0.0699121}, {74.9655, -0.0530811}, 
{75.1307, -0.0473759}, {75.2959, -0.0496924}, {75.4611, -0.0424499}, 
{75.6263, -0.0241374}, {75.7915, -0.0436916}, {75.9567, -0.089127}, 
{76.1219, -0.0761635}, {76.2871, -0.0538311}, {76.4522, -0.0522625}, 
{76.6174, -0.0747319}, {76.7826, -0.0739987}, {76.9478, -0.0333077}, 
{77.113, -0.00486031}, {77.2782, -0.0153005}, {77.4434, -0.0266643}, 
{77.6086, -0.0274922}, {77.7738, -0.0620418}, {77.939, -0.0877488}, 
{78.1042, -0.0803497}, {78.2694, -0.0537084}, {78.4346, -0.0425878}, 
{78.5998, -0.0402573}, {78.765, -0.0197596}, {78.9302, -0.0105323}, 
{79.0954, -0.0277539}, {79.2606, -0.0459642}, {79.4258, -0.0416842}, 
{79.591, -0.0456379}, {79.7561, -0.0775024}, {79.9213, -0.0816734}, 
{80.0865, -0.0372224}, {80.2517, -0.0110671}, {80.4169, -0.0447514}, 
{80.5821, -0.073486}, {80.7473, -0.0684747}, {80.9125, -0.0510865}, 
{81.0777, -0.0564664}, {81.2429, -0.05117}, {81.4081, -0.0249809}, 
{81.5733, -0.00204501}, {81.7385, -0.0035259}, {81.9037, 
-0.00623434}, {82.0689, -0.0128054}}}
```

When I plot these data with *Mathematica*, I get the following figure:

> [image: Overview]

By the way, this is a physical, non-local, spin valve signal at a given temperature.

What I need is a method to find the two switching fields (actually 4 if  negative values are also considered).

At present, I doing the following:

By hand, I make two linear fits, one for the area where the signal is constant at about $-3$ mOhm, one for the area where the signal is decreasing from $0$ mOhm to $-3$ mOhm. For all temperatures, the first area is nearly the same. In the second area, where is this strong decrease of the signal, I have to fit the line by hand. For this example it would be:

> ```
> {{35.3187, 0.779363}, {35.4839, -1.12199}, {35.6491, -2.55552}, 
>  {35.8143, -2.94135}, {35.9795, -3.09798}}
> ```

From these two lines, I get the intersection point which is what I am interessted in.

This method takes me about 10 min for each intersection point because I have to do it by hand, which is OK for one data set. For the 240 data sets that I have this would take a relativly long time, so I'm looking for a way to automate it.

The final result looks like this :

> [image: final result]

What I find especially difficult is getting *Mathematica* to find the correct values for the second line, because I usually have just 3 or 4 measured points for such lines.

I hope someone will respond with some nice ideas how this can be done automatically.

Comment: Have you considered directly [fitting a piecewise linear model](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45745/484)?

Answer (score 8):

Here is an other way using wavelets:

```
(*use only x values*)
d = Transpose[test][[2]];
(*Define Wavelet for flattening*)
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[d, HaarWavelet[]];
(*Use VisuShrink threshold*)
dwdt = WaveletThreshold[dwd, "VisuShrink"];
(*Get filtered values*)
flat = InverseWaveletTransform[dwdt];
(*Plot data and filtered values*)
ListLinePlot[{d, flat}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
(*Define threshold to select values of intrest*)
thresh = -3.2;
{min, max} = {Min@Select[flat, # < thresh &], 
   Max@Select[flat, # < thresh &]};
(*Find coordinates of intrest*)
pt1 = Flatten@{ test\[Transpose][[1, Last@Position[flat, max]]], max};
pt2 = Flatten@{test\[Transpose][[1, First@Position[flat, min]]], min};
pts = {pt1, pt2}
(*RESULT*)
```

> {{42.2569, -3.20194}, {51.0122, -3.21601}}

Answer (score 5):

```
 baseline = NonlinearModelFit[test[[;; 200]],
    ((a + b) - (a - b)  Erf[c ( t - d ) ])/
        2 , {{a, 0}, {b, -3}, {c, 1}, {d, 40}}  , t];
 baseline2 = NonlinearModelFit[test[[120 ;;]],
    ((a + b) - (a - b)  Erf[c ( t - d ) ])/
        2 , {{a, 0}, {b, -3}, {c, 1}, {d, 40}}  , t];
 cp = {d, baseline[d]} /. baseline["BestFitParameters"];
 slope = D[baseline[x], x] /. x -> d /. baseline["BestFitParameters"];
 ip = {cp[[1]] + (  b - cp[[2]] )/slope, b} /. baseline["BestFitParameters"];
 cp2 = {d, baseline2[d]} /. baseline2["BestFitParameters"];
 slope2 = D[baseline2[x], x] /. x -> d /.  baseline2["BestFitParameters"];
 ip2 = {cp2[[1]] + (  a - cp2[[2]] )/slope2, a} /. baseline2["BestFitParameters"];
 Show[{ListPlot[test], 
     Plot[ baseline[x], {x, 0, 80}, PlotStyle -> Red],
     ListPlot[{ip, ip2},PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@Circle[], .09}],
       Graphics[{Line[{{cp[[1]] + ( 1 - cp[[2]] )/slope, 1},
                       {cp[[1]] + ( 1.2 b - cp[[2]] )/slope, 1.2 b} }
           /. baseline["BestFitParameters"]]}]} ,
            PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

I think these are  the numbers you are after:

```
 {ip,ip2} - > {{35.6812, -3.20843}, {54.3617, -3.20473}}
```

Edit:
 better yet you can get that fit in one shot with

```
 NonlinearModelFit[test,
    a - (a - b)  (Erf[ c (t - d) ] - Erf[c2 ( t - d2 )])/2 ,
        {{a, 0}, {b, -3}, {c, 1}, {c2, 1}, {d, 20}, {d2, 80}}  , t]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very good, thank you for all your effort

Answer (score 2):

You can use and make more general the following method:

```
pos = ImageValuePositions[Image[EdgeDetect[Image@test]], 1][[ ;; , 1]]

jump = test[[ 1, ;; , 1]][[Floor[pos]]]

ListPlot[test, GridLines -> {jump, {}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red],
               Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.1]
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this method will  give the numeric correct value, a second thing is maybe that it is difficult to define an error with this method so I have to think about defining a graphical error. Would you tell me what Mathematica finds for the switching field in this example. I can not test from here because ImageValuePositions is Mathematica 9 and I have just Version 8 here. I have to think about your method but thank you very much

Comment: @Alexander Ok, but what exactly do you need? The temperature of switch? Because your method gives the point that is closer the $-3$ level than $0~$. p.s. `ImageValuePositions` gives `{118.5, 233.5}`.

Comment: No the temperature of each file is given, i need in my figure the x value of the intersection of the two lines what is the switching field, so you get with your method a vertical line ( I can not test here so I am not sure if it always a vertical line) but I am not sure if a vertical line would describe the physical situation in the best way because it is not really a heaviside step function because there are 3-6 values between the 0 mOhm and the -3 mOhm Signal. Would your method consider these points? I just saw your edit: What is 118.5 for a coordinate? Should it not be about 35?

Comment: I'm not improving your method, It is different one. I'm looking for a switch with gradient approach. Red line is only a visualisation of the x values that were found.

Comment: Yes of couse I see, but i do not understand your value of {118.5 , 233.5}. It is not the x1/x2/ value of the given figure, because you can see with pure eyes that the switching fields are at about 35 x value for first and about 55 x value for second switching, so I can not see the link between the values. Even the ratio of 118.5/35 and 233.5/55 is clearly different so I am a bit surprised

Comment: @Alexander Those are image coordinates of the switch where each pixel is a value from your `test`, so in the next line I'm taking `x` value from `test` that is on 118 and 233 place.