# Is there a way to fit a piecewise linear function to a list?

Tags: piecewise, fitting

I need to find a piecewise linear function that is a proper approximation for sunrise/sunset times of each day of year. Due to some limitations, I cannot use any trigonometric functions. So the sine-looking function has to be approximated by a piecewise linear one. Here is the code to generate data:

```
location = GeoPosition[{30, 60}];
year = DateRange["2022/3/21", "2023/3/21"];
sunrises = DateDifference[#, Sunrise[location, #], "Minute"] & /@ year;
sunsets = DateDifference[#, Sunset[location, #], "Minute"] & /@ year;
```

The sunrise data looks like this

[image: sunrise]

I want to approximate this function by $8$ straight lines. Thus the proposed function is defined as

[image: piecewise linear]

```
r[x_] := Piecewise[{
 {393 + ((-393 + b)*(-1 + x))/(-1 + x2), x <= x2},
 {b + ((-b + c)*(x - x2))/(-x2 + x3), x2 < x && x <= x3},
 {c + ((-c + d)*(x - x3))/(-x3 + x4), x3 < x && x <= x4},
 {d + ((-d + e)*(x - x4))/(-x4 + x5), x4 < x && x <= x5},
 {e + ((-e + f)*(x - x5))/(-x5 + x6), x5 < x && x <= x6},
 {f + ((-f + g)*(x - x6))/(-x6 + x7), x6 < x && x <= x7},
 {g + ((393 - g)*(x - x7))/(-x7 + x8), x7 < x && x <= x8}},
 393 + ((-393 + i)*(x - x8))/(366 - x8)]
```

Now the problem is, I cannot find such fit using any functions that I have tried. The closest thing that I have found was [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45745/37848), whose proposed method failed with this error:

```
FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {0.,0.0204082,<<364>>} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {366} at {b,c,d,e,f,g,h,x2,x3,x4,<<4>>} = {370.,350.,<<12>>}.
```

FWIW, I did set the initial values, as suggested there

```
init = {{b, 340}, {c, 320}, {d, 340}, {e, 390}, {f, 430}, {g, 450}, {h, 430},
 {x2, 50}, {x3, 80}, {x4, 120}, {x5, 200}, {x6, 270}, {x7, 300}, {x8, 330}};
NonlinearModelFit[First /@ sunrises, r[x], init, x]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would `ListInterpolation[sunrises, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` work? Also, [Extracting the function from InterpolatingFunction object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/26598)

Comment: @Roman no, it didn't work. I want the intervals to be exactly calculated. Since the function will be implemented in an embedded device with C

Comment: Can you afford more multiplications on the embedded CPU? If so, you can try fitting a cubic or a quartic. Now you have one multiplication, one addition and 3 comparisons. A quartic needs 4 multiplications and 4 additions, if you rewrite it into the form `a0+x(a1+x(a2+x(a3+a4 x)))`. Too expensive?

Comment: This is not what you asked for, but once you have the Chebyshev series to approximate the function, the function can be evaluated using only arithmetic via Clenshaw's algorithm. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115621/4999

Comment: You're missing the variable `i` in `init`, but it doesn't really fix things, although `NonLinearModelFit` will give an answer if you include it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you. That fixed the problem [facepalm emoji]

Comment: For such a small embedded system I'd suggest using a lookup table instead. Each dataset can be expressed as an offset plus a 7-bit (integer) number, so 2*366 bytes should be sufficient for looking up both sunrises and sunsets.

Answer (score 6):

You were on the right track.

I fitted the simular function `data = Table[-70 Sin[x] + 400 // N, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/365}];`  because didn't get sunrise data.

```
data = Table[-70 Sin[x] + 400 // N, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/365}]; 

ListPlot[data]

r[x_] = Piecewise[{{a + ((-a + b)*(-1 + x))/(-1 + x2), 
0 < x <= x2}, {b + ((-b + c)*(x - x2))/(-x2 + x3), 
x2 < x && x <= x3}, {c + ((-c + d)*(x - x3))/(-x3 + x4), 
x3 < x && x <= x4}, {d + ((-d + e)*(x - x4))/(-x4 + x5), 
x4 < x && x <= x5}, {e + ((-e + f)*(x - x5))/(-x5 + x6), 
x5 < x && x <= x6}, {f + ((-f + g)*(x - x6))/(-x6 + x7), 
x6 < x && x <= x7}, {g + ((h - g)*(x - x7))/(-x7 + x8), 
x7 < x && x <= x8}}, h + ((-h + i)*(x - x8))/(366 - x8)]

init = {{a, 380}, {b, 340}, {c, 320}, {d, 340}, {e, 390}, {f, 
   430}, {g, 450}, {h, 390}, {i, 390}, {x2, 50}, {x3, 80}, {x4, 
   120}, {x5, 200}, {x6, 270}, {x7, 300}, {x8, 330}}

nlfit = NonlinearModelFit[data, r[x], init, x]

nlfit["BestFitParameters"]

(*   {a -> 398.58, b -> 343.842, c -> 327.174, d -> 344.802, e -> 451.384, 
 f -> 470.609, g -> 467.262, h -> 445.643, i -> 400.682, 
 x2 -> 51.9572, x3 -> 91.9915, x4 -> 134.41, x5 -> 229.068, 
 x6 -> 264.087, x7 -> 295.086, x8 -> 326.01}   *)

Plot[nlfit[x], {x, 0, 366}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[.005], Point@Transpose[{Range[366], data}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[.015]}]
```

[image]

It is interesting to observe, you do not get absoute symmetry here, although this data are symmetric. Seems Fit doesn't find the global minimum of leastsquares. Think, it depends on initial values you give.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with 8 straight lines. It still needs  some fine tuning, but this you can do yourself:

```
x[0] = 1; x[1] = 60; x[2] = 80; x[3] = 110; x[4] = 200; x[5] = 280; 
x[6] = 300; x[7] = 320;x[8] = 360;
fit[x_] = 
 Piecewise[
  Transpose[{Fit[
       Transpose[{Table[x, {x, x[#[[1]]], x[#[[2]]]}], 
         sunrises[[x[#[[1]]] ;; x[#[[2]]]]]}], {1, x}, x], 
      x[#[[1]]] <= x <= x[#[[2]]]}] & /@ Partition[Range[0, 8], 2, 1]]
Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 1, 350}, PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[sunrises]]
```

[image]

Comment: The discretization points are fixed here. Is there any way to optimize them too?

Comment: You could do this, but I think it is not worth the effort, you can do it by hand. Otherwise you would define a function of the points that makes the fits and returns  the sum of squared deviations. Then you would use a minimization function to minimize the sum of squares.